# ASP.NET WebAPI and jQuery with large dataset (json)

Tags: jquery, json, sql-server, asp.net-web-api

I have a server side web API developed in ASP.NET MVC 5.0 using C#, and it generates a large volume of data in JSON format (~25MB) reading from SQL Server back-end. When this API is called inside my jQuery client-side, the request/response is completed successfully, but it takes ~5 minutes before it renders the result (report) in the HTML page.

I would like to seek if you have a pattern or code snippet where I can download the data in chunks (or streaming) so I don't have to wait the entire 5 minutes to be completed before the page renders the report.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you checked how much time the DB query is taking to fetch the data?

Comment: there is no problem in generating the result from server-side, the SQL profile only took < 3 seconds to generate the resultset. The problem is the payload it sends to the client as response. Using Fiddler, the JSON is almost 25MB in size.

Comment: as we speak the size is now ~48MB, because daily, the data is growing

Answer (score 2):

Before you go for streaming, I have few suggestions to improve the performance.

1- Try to reduce the payload. You can do it by using small alias name of your properties. For example.

```
[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "mbpn")]
 public string MyBigPropertyName{ get; set; }
```

This will reduce your overall payload (25+ MB) by a big number. I have personal experience where my data from 60 MB got reduced to 6 MB.

2- Choose a fast `JSON` serializer. You can check the performance comparison [here](http://theburningmonk.com/2014/08/json-serializers-benchmarks-updated-2/)

3- At the Clint side, don't bind the whole data in a single go, append the DOM in chunks.

4- User virtualization at client side.

If you still want to go for streaming, you can check this [link](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1180464/Large-JSON-Array-Streaming-in-ASP-NET-Web-API).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions and recommended link.

Answer (score 1):

I found a plugin that helped me, it's called jsonpipe, from https://github.com/eBay/jsonpipe